# jQuery Mobile stick footer always in bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've seen many topics but none of them is like what I want.
Here's an example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/444/

The **first page**, shows that the footer overlap the listview if the `data-position='fixed'` is set, and I don't want it to overlap.

The **second page** doesn't use the property `data-position='fixed'`, although, if I have no values in listview, the **footer doesn't stay at bottom**.

How can I stick the footer in bottom and don't overlap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then using position:fixed. you could use a wrapper to push the footer down,

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
   <div id="content">
    your list / content
   </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
 height:100%;
padding-bottom:100px; /* Footer height */
 }
footer {
height:100px;
margin-top:-100px,/* Footer height */
}
```